# Node.JS HTTPS JSON Parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

Just want a quick sanity check...

**Note**: this is a question from a coding assessment. I already submitted it and screenshotted the question for later review since I am almost positive it's just wrong and improperly defined. I suppose we'll just have to take it on the honor system that I'm not trying to cheat (I'm not).

Took a coderbyte assessment today and received this problem statement:

Node.js Debugging JSON Data

In the JavaScript file, you have a program that performs a GET request on the route https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting [you can hit the API in your browser to see the data] which contains a data key and the value which is a string which contains items in the format: key=STRING, age=INTEGER.

Your goal is to print out the key ID's between indices 10 and 15 in the string format (eg. q3kG6,MGQpf,tg2VM,...). The program provided already parses the data and loops through each item, but you need to figure out how to fix it so that it correctly populates keyArray with only key ID's.

The provided shell

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting', (resp) => {

    let content = '';

    resp.on('data', (c) => content += c);

    resp.on('end', () => {
        let jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
        let jsonContentArray = jsonContent.data.split(",");
        let keyArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < jsonContentArray.length; i++) {
            let keySplit = jsonContentArray[i].trim().split("=");
            keyArray.push(keySplit[1]);
        }

        return keyArray;

})
```

My attempted solution

```
const https = require('https");

https.get('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting', (resp) => {

    let content = '';

    resp.on('data', (c) => content += c);

    resp.on('end', () => {
        let jsonContent = JSON.parse(content);
        let jsonContentArray = jsonContent.data.split(",");
        let keyArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < jsonContentArray.length; i++) {
            let keySplit = jsonContentArray[i].trim().split("=");
            if (jsonContentArray[i].trim().startsWith("key")) {
                keyArray.push(keySplit[1]);
            }
        }
        
        let keyArrayLimited = [];
        for (let i = 10; i < 16; i++) {
            keyArrayLimited.push(keyArray[i]);
        }


        return keyArrayLimited;

})
```

Just to make sure I'm not going insane (I complained to the hiring manager).

Ambiguities in the problem statement:

The question definition doesn't specify what "indices" is relative to. This could be either relative to the unfiltered array (with age elements included) or the filtered array (with only key elements). It also could be inclusive or exclusive (this also isn't specified).

Just plain wrong example provided:

Further it then goes on to provide an example that implies the question intended to specify indices relative to the filtered array (only key elements), inclusively, but even then the answer it provides omits one of the elements it should've included in this definition.

Problem statement claims (eg. q3kG6,MGQpf,tg2VM,...), omitting Kj6XW.

Presuming my answer is actually correct or the best I could do given the context. Am I crazy?

Comment: Why are you using `https` instead of the now-universal Fetch api?

Comment: Not my code. Shell was provided by Coderbyte platform